# How is Morpha Lemmatizer Used?

Tags: lemmatization

I'm intending to use SQL version of WordNet and I have a problem finding a way to lemmatize words in order to find them in the DB; I can't use the WordNet lemmatizer itself because it is applied to the textual version of WorldNet.

I've read here that there is a good lemmatizer that returns real words - and that's exactly what I need.  I downloaded "Morpha", the suggested lemmatizer, but I don't understand how to use it.

- Is any compilation needed?
- Which file should I use?
- How can I use it in an application that accesses the WordNet SQL DB?

Comment: +1 for teaching me a new word (and concept)

Answer (score 1):

The UW has [uploaded morpha stemmer to Maven central](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/edu.washington.cs.knowitall/morpha-stemmer).  There's a wrapper that makes it much easier to use.  You just need to add it as a dependency and use the `edu.washington.cs.knowitall.morpha.MorphaStemmer` class.  Instances are threadsafe (the original JFlex had class fields for local variables unnecessarily).  Instantiate a class and run `morpha` and the word you want to stem.

```
new MorphaStemmer().morpha("climbed") // goes to "climb"
```

Answer (score 0):

[Minnen et al's paper on Morpha](http://www.informatics.susx.ac.uk/research/groups/nlp/carroll/papers/minnen.pdf) might be a good place to start to understand how the lemmatizer works.  It's been a while since I'd had any experience with it myself, but I'm pretty sure it works just as an off-the-shelf binary.

Depending on performance, you may need to POS-tag your terms beforehand, but that's about the same issue you'll have querying WordNet, so it's starting to sound like you'll need to climb that hill either way.

You would basically use the root form when querying the Wordnet DB, but if you're using it just for that, I'd urge you to try the Morphy stemmer, which was specifically designed for Wordnet, and will reliably match to the root forms listed therein.

Answer (score 0):

You also might want to check out TTT2, an NLP Pipeline that tokenizes, lemmatizes etc. all in one or separately. Easy to use and well documented:
http://www.ltg.ed.ac.uk/software/lt-ttt2

Answer (score 0):

You must have by now found your answer, but for anyone else who might stumble upon this post about Morpha:

you can download Morpha directly from:
http://www.informatics.susx.ac.uk/research/groups/nlp/carroll/morph.html

But this requires flex to be installed first, decompressed and compiled (I'm using the Linux terminal command line below):

```
tar -xzf flex-for-morph.tar.gz
```

Then change the current working directory to flex and make it:

```
./configure
make
```

If the make command gives the following error:

make: yacc: Command not found
Makefile:105: recipe for target 'parse.c' failed
make: *** [parse.c] Error 127

it means it cannot get yacc; so you need to install bison via command line:

```
sudo apt-get install bison
```

Now run the make command again, it should give you something similar to this at the last line:

```
gcc -g -O -o flex  ccl.o dfa.o ecs.o gen.o main.o misc.o nfa.o parse.o scan.o skel.o sym.o tblcmp.o yylex.o  libfl.a
```

Now you're good to compile Morpha (which you downloaded from above link):

```
../flex-2.5.4/flex -i -Cfe -8 -omorpha.yy.c morpha.lex
gcc -o morpha morpha.yy.c
```

Morpha takes the already-POS-tagged files as input. To lemmatise a single file use:

```
./morpha -t  < ~/path to your file/yourfile.tag
```

the -t option above prints the POS tags also along with the lemmatised forms; to use the case-sensitive option use -c and for both options together use -ct

Hope it helps!